# Need help with MySQL query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute the following query statement contained within a Stored Procedure -
Where all P... are parameters to SP (ex PInitialDateFrom).

```
SET @stmt_text = CONCAT('SELECT AccountID, Firstname as ClientName, EmailID
                 , ProductID, InitialPurchaseDate as Purchasedate 
                 FROM client_account 
                 WHERE IsRemoved = 0 
                 AND (InitialPurchasedate between ? and ?) 
                 AND ProductId IN (?)');

PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt_text;

SET @initDt1=PInitialDateFrom, @initDt2 = PInitialDateTo, @inlist=PIDs
    , @stmt_text = null;

EXECUTE stmt USING @initDt1, @initDt2, @inlist;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I am passing PID's as a string of ids like 1,2,3 
When I try to execute the statement, only the first id is considered. For ex. 1,2,3 is used only 1 is taken, if 3,2,1 is used only 3 is taken.

Can anybody tell what's wrong with this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use this part:

```
and ProductId in (?)
```

Remember: SQL parameters are not like `C` macros where you are just doing string replacements. They are more than thar: When you use `?`, **one and only one** parameter gets bound. So, when you try to bind `1,2,3` to that parameter, it's not like you are trying to bind three values but only one.

If your list is going to be of fixed size, you could use:

```
and ProductId in (?,?,?)
```

Otherwise, I don't think you will be able to use parameters for that clause. Maybe doing something like:

```
set @initDt1=PInitialDateFrom, 
    @initDt2 = PInitialDateTo, 
    @inlist=PIDs,  
    @stmt_text = null;
set @stmt_text = 
   concat('Select AccountID, Firstname as ClientName, EmailID, ProductID
     , InitialPurchaseDate as Purchasedate from client_account 
     where IsRemoved=0 and (InitialPurchasedate between ? and ?) 
     and ProductId in (', @inlist, ')');
prepare stmt from @stmt_text;
execute stmt using @initDt1, @initDt2;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Make sure you sanitize your input for `PIDs` so you don't add SQLInjection vulnerabilities to your code.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. Is there any other way like splitting string into an array?

Comment: Try doing as I showed you in the last example. Not using your list as a parameter for your query, but concatenating it in the original string. Make sure you sanitize your input so you don't add SQLInjection vulnerabilities to your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should put it like this:

```
and ProductID = (?)
```

I hope it works.

Comment: Thanks, but its not working. And i thing = will not work as i need to take values from a group.